# Cannot get simple AWS web socket publish to work

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I wrote this uber simple client to publish a message to aws sdk via websocket protocol (javascript version). https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js

```
var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');

var device = awsIot.device({
    region: "us-west-2",
    protocol: "wss",
    clientId: "ARUNAVS SUPER TEST",
    host: "iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
    port: "443"
});

device
  .on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connect');
    device.publish('abcd', JSON.stringify({ test_data: 1}));
  });

device
    .on('message', function(topic, payload) {
    console.log('message', topic, payload.toString());
  });

device
  .on('error', function(error) {
     console.log('error', error);
  });
```

I am getting the following error (after importing admin creds https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js#websockets):-

```
node testCode.js

error { Error: unexpected server response (403)
at ClientRequest._req.on 
(/Users/arunavs/mrtests/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:653:21)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:472:21)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:105:23)
at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:361:20)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:177:18)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:135:10)
type: 'error',
target:
 WebSocket {
 domain: null,
 _events: {},
 _eventsCount: 0,
 _maxListeners: undefined,
 readyState: 3,
 bytesReceived: 0,
 extensions: null,
 protocol: '',
 _binaryType: 'arraybuffer',
 _finalize: [Function: bound finalize],
 _closeFrameReceived: false,
 _closeFrameSent: false,
 _closeMessage: '',
 _closeTimer: null,
 _finalized: true,
```

The SDK fails to give any reason why I am getting a 403.

Note : According to https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js/blob/234d170c865586f4e49e4b0946100d93f367ee8f/device/index.js#L142, the code is even presigning using sigv4, as part of my output also has

```
 url: 'wss://iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443/mqtt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential= .......
```

Has anyone seen an error like this?

Comment: `iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` is the endpoint for the IOT service API.  [It looks like](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html) the endpoint you need would be a subdomain of that, e.g. `jozxyqkexample.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: Interesting point, though its not obvious what this subdomain entails (or why would i even need it if all i am doing is sending one Mqtt message over a websocket). Or its some kind of a AWS Iot thing registration?

Comment: Nope, tried out a thing registration and still gives me the exact same error. I do not think classifying a publish wrt to a thing is a requirement.

Comment: @Micheal-sqlbot I tried it again today with the thing name and the problem dissapeared. You are right in that the thing name is a necessity. Dunno why it was 403ing yesterday.

Comment: Correction, the endpoint can be gathered using the following CLI command : aws iot describe-endpoint --region us-west-2
{
    "endpointAddress": "......"
} Its not related to thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are publish on the THING which does not allow all users to connect with it.

Can you post the details of the policy of the thing that you are trying to publish message on.

> On the Create a policy page, in the Name field, type a name for the
>   policy (for example, MyIoTButtonPolicy). In the Action field, type
>   iot:Connect. In the Resource ARN field, type *. Select the Allow
>   checkbox. This allows all clients to connect to AWS IoT.

Read more about [POLICIES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-policies.html).

PS: This is just a wild guess. Please post policy details in the question so that I can be sure.